# Timeout when trying to have ansible delete a file on cisco routers

Tags: command, ansible, cisco

Im having errors in my playbook when I try to delete files from the flash of my cisco IOS router. Below is the code and underneath is the error I am getting

```
 - ios_command:
  commands: "delete flash:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.155-3.M.bin\r"


 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "timeout trying to send command: delete flash:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.155-3.M.bin", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: Can you perform any commands on the router? Maybe a simple show or something?

Comment: This command would work if I typed it in manually without the "/r".

Comment: Is that your problem? Are you wanting it to be "/r or /recursive"? Instead of "\r" like you have in your command. You could also throw a "/force" on it and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem is that when attempting to delete the file the route prompts for a confirmation. Usually /r works to confirm but it's not in this case. /force doesn't help either

Comment: Oh I see its asking for a user confirmation and you have no way to input that and bypassing it with "/r" isn't working. 


Depending on what version of Ansible you are running you could try, `authorize: yes` or `connection: network_cli` and `become: yes` with `become_pass`.


http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_command_module.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the command is asking for confirmation and `/r` is not working. According to Ansible's documentation you can use the "prompt" parameter with the ios_command module.

**Example from Documentation**
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_command_module.html

```
  - name: run command that requires answering a prompt
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - command: 'clear counters GigabitEthernet0/2'
          prompt: 'Clear "show interface" counters on this interface [confirm]'
          answer: c
```

And in your case, you should run the command manually to see what the prompt is and the required answer, then fill in the `prompt` and `answer` parameters.

**Example delete from flash** (*Update with correct parameters*)

```
  - name: run command that requires answering a prompt
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - command: 'delete flash:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.155-3.M.bin'
          prompt: 'Delete "flash:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.155-3.M.bin" from flash [confirm]'
          answer: c
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post this in-case someone else stumbles here in the future.  The typical file prompt dialog is as follows and actually requires response for two separate prompts.

```
switch_name#delete c2960s-universalk9-mz.152-7.E2.bin
Delete filename [c2960s-universalk9-mz.152-7.E2.bin]?
Delete flash:/c2960s-universalk9-mz.152-7.E2.bin? [confirm]
```

Dealing with two prompts in ansible proved difficult, so I configured "file prompt quiet" on the network switch.
This configuration will make the switch prompt only for confirmation and its easy to confirm in your playbook.

```
- command: Delete {{ old_image_path }}
  prompt: Delete {{ old_image_path }}\? \[confirm\]
  answer: 'y'
```